# How to sort div container content vertically using css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display div container content vertically (One under another). using css.

```
<div class="container">

    <div>
    <h1 class="enwan">This is an h1 element</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
    <h2 class="enwan">This is an h1 element</h2>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    display:block;
}
.enwan {
    float:right;
    color:rgb(241, 93, 177);
    border-right: solid 10px;
    border-left: solid 10px;
    border-style:dotted;
    padding:50px;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

Tried display:block; but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:right;`. The entire point of `float` is to let subsequent content move up *beside* the element to which it is applied.